# Click on item using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to click on the "Training material statistics" by using the following code in Python, but it didn't work:

```
WebDriverWait(driver,20)\
    .until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="report-navigation"]/div[2]')))\
    .click()
```

---

HTML:

```
<div id="report-navigation">
    <div class="report-nav-btn active" onclick="Report.changeGrid(this, 'report-users-grid')">
       User statistics          
       <div class="report-nav-arrow active"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="report-nav-btn" onclick="Report.changeGrid(this, 'report-objects-grid')">
       Training material statistics         
       <div class="report-nav-arrow"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="report-nav-btn" onclick="Report.changeGrid(this, 'report-deliverables-grid')">
       Learner assignments          
       <div class="report-nav-arrow"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

HTML Snapshot:

[image: HTML Image]

Comment: HTML? Code? Error message? You need to give us some more info.

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193625/how-to-click-on-a-element-through-selenium-python/54194511#54194511) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#report-navigation div[onclick*='report-objects-grid']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='report-navigation']//div[contains(@onclick, 'report-objects-grid')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```